# iPad stops responding to bonjour/zeroconf after name change

Tags: ios, ipad, bonjour, zeroconf

iPad4 running iOS 6.1.

It responds to bonjour/mdns requests under its current name (eg ping example.local).

Go to Settings > General > About > Name and change name (eg to newname).

iPad stops responding to mdns requests. Wireshark shows no response from the ipad.

Reboot/reset network and all settings has no effect. Under Xcode, console shows:

mDNSResponder[31] : User updated Computer Name from “example” to “newname”
mDNSResponder[31] : User updated Local Hostname from “example” to “newname”

The iPad shows up as "newname" under iTunes and XCode, so the device's friendly name is OK.
It also sends out mdns requests (eg browsing for http://somewhere.local).

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer from [eskimo1](https://devforums.apple.com/people/eskimo1) on the Apple developer forums here:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/899667#899667

that explains that an iOS device won't publish an "A" record (ie newname.local) unless there is also an app running that has published a service to Bonjour/mdns as well.

The logic is sound in that if the iPad is not offering any services, then there is no reason to publish its information via mdns.

The alternative is either a) have an app running that publishes a service or b) set up dynamic DNS to register devices as they DHCP when connecting to your local network.